# Создание Entry-Point для динамической dll

Tags: c#, c++

Моя задача - сделать запуск программы при инжекте моей dll в сторонний процесс.
ЯП - C#.

С самого начала я думал об том, чтобы просто сделать в C# dll метод Main, но увы в C# нельзя сделать( Так мне все говорят ) так же, как в C++.
Тогда я решил добавить в моё решение C++ проект "Динамическая библиотека C++" и уже через Entry-Point C++ dll вызывать Main моей C# библиотеки.

В итоге, сразу после создания библиотеки на меня посыпались ошибки, я спросил всех C++ друзей - говорят что ситуация очень странная и они не знают решения.

Код C# dll:

```
//Program.cs
namespace PissPissInAJar;
using static FuckSharp;
public class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) => new F(@"C:\\t.txt").AL = "Entry point!"; //Запись в файл текста, проверял в ConsoleApp - работает. Так же Main без args.
}
```

Код C++(Сгенерирован автоматически)

```
// dllmain.cpp : Определяет точку входа для приложения DLL.
#include "pch.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

```
// pch.cpp: файл исходного кода, соответствующий предварительно скомпилированному заголовочному файлу

#include "pch.h"

// При использовании предварительно скомпилированных заголовочных файлов необходим следующий файл исходного кода для выполнения сборки.
```

```
#pragma once

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Исключите редко используемые компоненты из заголовков Windows
// Файлы заголовков Windows
#include <windows.h>
```

В dllmain.cpp файле выдаёт ошибку - "требуется точка с запятой"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А вторая ошибка в файле framework.h - "не удалось открыть источник файл "windows.h""
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не проще ли инжектить в CLR среду управляемую библиотеку, а не нативную? Вы не можете вызвать Main C# библиотеки до тех пор, пока его не скомпилит JIT. Но я скорее всего не улавливаю суть задачи.

Comment: Сторонний процесс на каком языке? C++? Вернее, какого типа процесс: управляемый или нативный? / Вопрос вообще в чём? Если он про написание dll на C#, то зачем в нём огрызки кода C++? Если он про компилирование C++, то зачем всё остальное про инжект и C#?

Comment: [ModuleInitializerAttribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.moduleinitializerattribute?view=net-6.0) позволит выполнить код при инициализации сборки. / Вот ещё способы: [Executing code before Main in .NET](https://www.meziantou.net/executing-code-before-main-in-dotnet.htm).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, не важно на каком языке, инжект длл даёт понять длл с памятью какого процесса нужно управлять.

Comment: @aepot, вероятно - да, можете для теста просто обычным Process Hacker 2 заинжектить в блокот получившуюся dll и посмотреть, выполнится ли код (например запись в файл текста через File)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, нет, ничего не помогло, я думаю нужно искать решение именно С++ ошибки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл пару костыльных библиотек (Одна из таких - DLLExport)
Но они все работают лишь в Console App, при переносе их в Dynamic DLL они переставали работать.

Сам же фикс ошибок в VS решился установкой пакета C++ для windows (как на скрине)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]